# Trigger custom Javascript function from twig template

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I just want to trigger a custom javascript function when the site is loaded
I have done this with Drupal.behaviors.custom, but it somehow behaviors triggers twice and I see two identical tables.
The problem is that I am a beginner and dont know how implement the once() function in my case

custom.js:

```
Drupal.behaviors.startTable = {
        attach: function () {

            var data = function () {
                return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 10);
            };

            var container = document.getElementById('example');

            var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data(),
                minSpareCols: 1,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                rowHeaders: true,
                colHeaders: true,
                contextMenu: true
            });


        }
    }
```

Best solution for me would be If I can trigger a Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.custom Command and trigger it with the template

Here is the call for the template:

```
public function handsontable()
{
   return [
      '#theme' => 'mytheme',
      '#attached' => ['library' => ['ajax_example/handsontable']],
         ];
}
```

Iam also able to call the custom js with a CommandInterface but it only works if there is a callback with a Link or button or from.

I am pretty sure that there is a really easy way, but could not find any solution.

twig template:

```
<h2>Handsontable Basic Example (100x10)</h2>
<p>
    Head to <a href="https://handsontable.com" target="_blank">handsontable.com</a> to learn more about Handsontable.
</p>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Maybe it is possible to call the custom js with the twig template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this.

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.startTable = {
    attach: function () {
      var container = $('#example');
      $(window).once().on('load', function () {
        var data = function () {
          return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 10);
        };
        var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
          data: data(),
          minSpareCols: 1,
          minSpareRows: 1,
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: true,
          contextMenu: true
        });
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

your library then needs:
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal

Comment: that worked thanks a lot.
The only problem was, I got serveral errors using $('#example');
Had to change it to document.getElementById('example');
Is this because of 'use strict' ?